# Tap event bubbling after hide target div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, tap

I use photoswipe plugin.  Photoswipe close when i tap close button. But after photoswipe hided,  div tap event  triggered on image that was under photoswipe div. How i can prevent this behavior?
For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

            div
            {
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
            }
            .first
            {
                background-color: black;
            }

            .second
            {
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                position: absolute;
                top : 50px;
                left: 50px;
                background-color: red;
                z-index: 2;
            }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
            $('.first').tap(function()
            {
                $(this).css({backgroundColor : 'green'});

            });

            $('.second').tap(function()
            {
                $(this).hide();
            });

        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='first'></div>
<div class='second'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

How it work
-tap second div
-fired tap event on second div
-second div hide
-fired tap event on first div

What i want
-tap second div
-fired tap event on second div
-second div hide
-nothing happening

What i should do in second div tap handler for prevent firing tap event on first div?

I changed example to see what events triggered

```
$(function()
        {
            $('.first').bind('vmousedown',function()
            {
                info('vmousedown first' )
            }).bind('vmouseup', function(){
                info('vmouseup first')
            })
            .bind('click',function(){
                info('click first');
            }).bind('tap', function(){
                info('tap first');
            });

            $('.second').bind('vmousedown',function()
            {
                info('vmousedown second' )
            }).bind('vmouseup', function(){
                info('vmouseup second');
            })
            .bind('click',function(){
                 info('click second');
            }).bind('tap', function(){
                 info('tap second');
                 $(this).hide();
            });

        });
```

PC output:
vmousedown second
vmouseup second
click second
tap second

Android :
vmousedown second
vmouseup second
tap second
vmousedown first
vmouseup first
click first
tap first

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the problem is you are using jQM Alpha (jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.js), upgrading to the latest release I think it works as expected. Also you might bind the tap event `.bind('tap', function()`

- http://jsfiddle.net/LFPNC/

JS

```
$(function()
{
    $('.first').tap(function()
    {
        $(this).css({backgroundColor : 'green'});

    });

    $('.second').tap(function()
    {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='first'></div>
<div class='second'></div>

</body>
</html>​
```

CSS

```
div
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
.first
{
    background-color: black;
}

.second
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top : 50px;
    left: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 2;
}​
```